# In ASP.NET Core, what class is used for model validation error responses?

Tags: asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core web API, I am using data annotations for model validation. Here is one class that has these annotations:

```cs
class CreateUserRequest {
    [Required, RegularExpression("[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(20, MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

If a client tries to create a user with a password that is too short, I get this response body:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "password":[
            "The field password must be a string with a minimum length of 6 and a maximum length of 20."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId":"|a301aaae-43dd49e731beb073."
}
```

I would like all errors returned from the API to have a consistent structure, to make it easier for clients to handle errors. Is there a class I can use to get this same structure for other error cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for [`ValidationProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails).

If you want to return additional properties on your response, you can simply extend the abovementioned class and add whatever you need, then call [`ControllerBase.ValidationProblem(ValidationProblemDetails)`](https://learn.microsoft.com//dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ControllerBase_ValidationProblem_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_ValidationProblemDetails_) with an instance of your class instead of using the standard call to `BadRequest()`.