# Inconsistent behaviour: Error response object in ASP.NET Core when manually return BadRequest

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core REST Api with both, static and dynamic validation.

When I not specify a required property, the middleware automatically generates a nice error message:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "status": [
            "Required property 'status' not found in JSON. Path '', line 37, position 1."
        ]
    },
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "|a6b5a076-4b400dadb53f75e7."
}
```

I also have some kind of dynamic validation where I *manually* populate the ModelState and return a BadRequest.

Simplified example:

```
ModelState.AddModelError("smh_data.materials.country_of_origin", "Field is required.");
return BadRequest(ModelState);
```

But in this case, the response looks like this:

```
{
    "smh_data.materials.country_of_origin": [
        "Field is required."
    ]
}
```

**How can I get the same response object** including traceId, type, title and status like above?

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63035066/70345 (similar, but not quite the same).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling `return BadRequest()`, call [`return ValidationProblem()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.validationproblem). This will create a [`ValidationProblemDetails`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.validationproblemdetails) object set to `BadRequest`, populate it with your `ModelState` errors, and return it.

Overloads of `ValidationProblem()` allow for further customisation of the returned response.